# How to split the sample code below in source/header?

Tags: c++, boost, refactoring

Is there a nice way of splitting the following sample C++ code in source and header such that all the users of the server don't need to indirectly include headers that are really only needed for the server's internals ?
[Source listing for Daytime.3](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tutdaytime3/src.html)

```
//
// server.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2013 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

std::string make_daytime_string()
{
  using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
  time_t now = time(0);
  return ctime(&now);
}

class tcp_connection
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection>
{
public:
  typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

  static pointer create(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
  {
    return pointer(new tcp_connection(io_service));
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    message_ = make_daytime_string();

    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
        boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
          boost::asio::placeholders::error,
          boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
  }

private:
  tcp_connection(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
      size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket socket_;
  std::string message_;
};

class tcp_server
{
public:
  tcp_server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13))
  {
    start_accept();
  }

private:
  void start_accept()
  {
    tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
      tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_io_service());

    acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
        boost::bind(&tcp_server::handle_accept, this, new_connection,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer new_connection,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_connection->start();
    }

    start_accept();
  }

  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main()
{
  try
  {
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp_server server(io_service);
    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Most examples I can find assume all the code will be in a single file, for some reason.

The question might seem stupid, but every time I try to refactor this, some template decides to crash. I could really use the example.

Comment: What portion of this do you think could be moved to an implementation file and hidden from the user?

Comment: ideally, a user would only call `tcp_server->start()` or something similar API. Including the header, should not drag `asio.hpp` and other headers because the user does not care how the server is implemented.
I've read about PImpl but I'm convinced there has to be a better way. I any case I couldn't even manage to split this into something like `tcpserver.cpp`,`tcpserver.h` and `main.cpp` without errors from templates.

Comment: Well, right now you can't even create a `tcp_server` without passing it a `boost::asio::io_service`. It looks like there's a lot you could do to put function definitions in a separate source file, but anything that sees the definition of `tcp_server` is going to need to see the definition of `tcp::acceptor` as well and probably want to see the definition of `io_service`. Maybe look at the pointer-to-implementation idiom?

Answer (score 0):

The general answer to this is to use Pimpl Idiom. You can make the header as simple as

```
#pragma once
#include <memory>
class tcp_server {
  public:
    tcp_server();
    ~tcp_server();
    void run();

  private:
    struct impl;
    std::unique_ptr<impl> _pimpl;
};
```

Then `main.cpp` can be:

```
#include "server.h"
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    try {
        tcp_server server;
        server.run();
    } catch (std::exception const& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Of course, that leaves the question how you implement `test.cpp`:

```
tcp_server::tcp_server() : _pimpl(std::make_unique<impl>()) {}
void tcp_server::run() { _pimpl->run(); }
```

And all the logic has been moved to the implementation type and all local functions can have file linkage.

### Live Demo

**[Live On Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/L3SH4lD2Nr4zZO7A)**

- File `test.cpp`

  ```
   #include "server.h"
   #include <iostream>
   int main()
   {
       try {
           tcp_server server;
           server.run();
       } catch (std::exception const& e) {
           std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
       }
   }
  ```
- File `server.h`

  ```
   #pragma once
   #include <memory>
   class tcp_server {
     public:
       tcp_server();
       ~tcp_server();
       void run();

     private:
       struct impl;
       std::unique_ptr<impl> _pimpl;
   };
  ```
- File `server.cpp`

  ```
   #include "server.h"
   #include <boost/asio.hpp>
   #include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>
   #include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
   #include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
   #include <ctime>
   #include <string>

   using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

   namespace /*anonymous, file linkage*/ {
       static std::string make_daytime_string()
       {
           using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime;
           time_t now = time(0);
           return ctime(&now);
       }

       class tcp_connection
           : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<tcp_connection> {
         public:
           typedef boost::shared_ptr<tcp_connection> pointer;

           static pointer create(boost::asio::any_io_executor executor)
           {
               return pointer(new tcp_connection(executor));
           }

           tcp::socket& socket() { return socket_; }

           void start()
           {
               message_ = make_daytime_string();

               boost::asio::async_write(
                   socket_, boost::asio::buffer(message_),
                   boost::bind(&tcp_connection::handle_write, shared_from_this(),
                               boost::asio::placeholders::error,
                               boost::asio::placeholders::bytes_transferred));
           }

         private:
           tcp_connection(boost::asio::any_io_executor executor)
               : socket_(executor)
           {
           }

           void handle_write(const boost::system::error_code& /*error*/,
                             size_t /*bytes_transferred*/)
           {
           }

           tcp::socket socket_;
           std::string message_;
       };
   } // namespace

   struct tcp_server::impl {
       void run() { io_service_.run(); }
       void start_accept()
       {
           tcp_connection::pointer new_connection =
               tcp_connection::create(acceptor_.get_executor());

           acceptor_.async_accept(new_connection->socket(),
                                  boost::bind(&impl::handle_accept, this,
                                              new_connection,
                                              boost::asio::placeholders::error));
       }

       void handle_accept(tcp_connection::pointer          new_connection,
                          const boost::system::error_code& error)
       {
           if (!error) {
               new_connection->start();
           }

           start_accept();
       }

       boost::asio::io_service io_service_;
       tcp::acceptor acceptor_{io_service_, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), 13)};
   };

   tcp_server::tcp_server() : _pimpl(std::make_unique<impl>()) {}
   tcp_server::~tcp_server() = default;

   void tcp_server::run() { _pimpl->run(); }
  ```